# What is "outward going"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Curiously, Rodman didn't at first appear to be all that athletic or *outward going*. He was short for most of high school, just 5-6, and was cut from his high school football team and later quit the basketball team because he wasn't getting enough playing time

What does "outward going" means?

Comment: I think it should be outgoing in this context, not outward-going.  The outgoing is used for a person who is friendly and likes to be with or talk to new people.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds wrong. "Outgoing" seems to be the right word here.